# geodesic curvature in an isothermal parameterization.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

suppose the surface is covered by a conformal coordinate system, and the parameterization is called an isothermal parameterization.
Theorem . Let $\sigma:U\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow S  $ be a parameterization of a regular surface S such that the entries of the first fundamental form are

\begin{gathered}E=\lambda(u,v)\\
F=0\\
G=\lambda(u,v)
\end{gathered}

where $\lambda(u,v)>0$. Now let R be a region of the surface S. Then the local Gauss-Bonnet theorem says that

$\int_{R}KdA+\int_{\partial R}k_{g}ds+\sum_{\text{vertices }}\omega_{i}=2\pi$

Let $\sigma:U\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow S$ be an isothermal parameterization of a regular surface S,$R\in S$ be a piecewise smooth region of this surface and $\alpha:[a,b]\longrightarrow S$ be a curve such that $\left|\alpha^{\prime}(s)\right|=1$ and $\partial R=\alpha([a,b])$. Given that we have a conformal coordinate system, we can now write the geodesic curvature along $\alpha$ as $\alpha:[a,b]\longrightarrow S$

$$k_{g}(s)=\frac{1}{2\lambda}\left(\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial u}v^{\prime}-\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial v}u^{\prime}\right)+\frac{d\phi_{i}}{ds}$$

where $\phi_{i}$ is again a function measuring the positive angle from $\sigma_{u}$ to $\alpha^{\prime}(s) $

My quetion is how the geodesic curvature found?
Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

1. Because of the following proposition :

> For orthogonal parametrizations, the geodesic curvature of a curve parametrized by arc length ($|\alpha'(s)| = 1$) can be defined as :
> \begin{align*}
> \left[ \frac{D(\alpha')}{ds} \right] = (k_g)  = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}}\left( G_u v' - E_v u' \right) + \frac{d \phi_i}{ds}
> \end{align*}

By applying this expression to an isothermal coordinate system, you get your result.

2. If you are asking why (1.) is true, it's because it's derived from the following proposition :

> For two differentiable fields of unit vectors along a curve $\alpha$:
> $$ \left[ \frac{Dw}{ds} \right] = \left[ \frac{Dv}{ds} \right] + \frac{d\phi}{ds}$$
> Where $\phi$ is the angle from $v$ to $w$.

By applying that to your orthogonal parametrization, by setting $v = \sigma_1/\sqrt{E}$ (which transforms $v$ into a unit vector field) and $w = \alpha'$, and doing some calculations using orthogonality, you get the desired result of (1.).

3. If you are asking yourself why (2.) is true, that's because given two such fields of vectors, you can extend them so that $(v,\tilde{v})$ is orthonormal, which allows you to find a differentiable $\phi$ such that :

$$w = \cos(\phi)v + \sin(\phi)\tilde{v}$$

Starting from (3.) and doing some algebra, you get (2.) and then you get (1.)

The expression for $w$ shouldn't surprise you. Imagine you are watching footage of boat with a camera fixed to it, from above. You can see how the sail ($w$) changes it's angle with respect to some other axis $-$ for example, the direction in which the boat points ($v$), or any other axis on your screen. Therefore, it makes sense that you are able to define such an angle.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.

Comment: @MohammedAlbaraddouni You are welcome. Could you please accept my answer, if it was satisfying ?

Comment: If your words are right in 2., then there’s a sign error.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, not sure what happened there.

Comment: @Pastudent. thank you very much. Your answer was adequate and sufficient.